# Binomial Probability of airline booking

Tags: probability

An airline company is considering a new policy of booking as many as 312 persons on an airplane that can seat only 290. (Past studies have revealed that only 89% of the booked passengers actually arrive for the flight.) Estimate the probability that if the company books 312 persons. not enough seats will be available.

Here is what I did

:X ~ Bin(312,0.89) n=312 p=0.89

P(291<=X<=312)=0.007213144679

Am I right?Or I think it wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct.

Comment: 1. If you are using the $=$ sign,the answer $=$ 2030319730505/281474976710656, else use the $\approx$ sign. 2. The computation is so simple using technology that I think that you might be expected to use the normal approximation to the binomial.